# How to apply filter to all objects in nested array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have three radio buttons and want to display depending on the option values and should apply to each object in nested array.

```
// how to do the in nested object array for all `ids` and apply `options` 

code:

const id = "trans";
const options = option_values.find(({id:x}) => x===id).options;

[...document.getElementsByClassName("form-check-input")].filter(({
  value
}) => !options.includes(value)).forEach(elem => elem.style.display = 'none');

var option_value2 = [
{
  id:"trans",
  options: ["bank", "credit"]
},
{
  id:"fund",
  options: ["bank"]
}
]

<form>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-bank transfer-${provider.id}" value="bank" title="bank" checked>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-credit-${provider.id}" value="credit" title="credit">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-debit-${provider.id}" value="debit" title="debit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Change your array from `option_value2` to `option_values` and define it above the `const options = option_val
ues.find()` line. Your code will work fine

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have an array called `option_values` to call the `find` method of it. It should be `option_value2`

   ```
    const options = option_values.find(({id:x}) => x===id).options;
   ```
2. You are giving data to the array after calling the `find` method. It should be the other way around.

   ```
    var option_value2 = [
    {
      id:"trans",
      options: ["bank", "credit"]
    },
    {
      id:"fund",
      options: ["bank"]
    }
    ]

    const options = option_values.find(({id:x}) => x===id).options;
   ```